# In Maya, how can I delete with python some object in the node Mash/Repro?

Tags: python, maya

I have 56 objects in my node repromesh.

I have listed all the attributes of this node, but can't figure how to delete one (or all) the object in order to replace them with another.

There are some attribute like : instancedGroup.instancedMesh but no value/type I can find to access it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axyHq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite complex one : (**EDIT : solution for delete all in the bottom**)

if you go to this python file (i found this module by turning on echo all, while removing item) :

```
print(mash_repro_aetemplate.__file__)
```

You will find the mash script and the pieces where they call the UI.

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance 

usingPyside2 = False
try:
    import PySide2
    usingPyside2 = True
except:
    pass
from flux.imports import *
from flux.core import pix
import flux.core as fx

import mash_repro_utils
from mash_repro_icons import MASH_REPRO_ICONS

from functools import partial
import MASH.undo as undo

def get_maya_window():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return wrapInstance(long(ptr), qt.QMainWindow)

def refresh_all_aetemplates(force=False):
    """ Refresh all the repro aetemplates"""
    widgets = get_maya_window().findChildren(AEMASH_ReproTemplate) or []
    for widget in widgets:
        global SCENE_OPENED
        SCENE_OPENED = True
        widget.update_data(widget.node, force=force)
        SCENE_OPENED = False
```

here is a way to find the repro node :

```
widgets = get_maya_window().findChildren(qt.QWidget, 'AEMASH_ReproTemplate') or []
myRepro = widgets[0]
```

'myRepro' is now the class of the mash repro node.

The Qtreewidget representing your nodes is :

```
myRepro.objs_widget
```

you can use from this other class derived from qtree :

```
# work only on selection, if you want to modify this command, maybe create your own add_sel_bjects(self, objs=[])
myRepro.objs_widget.add_objects()


# work only on the selection in the qtree widget
myRepro.objs_widget.delete_item()

# you can use qtree functions instead :
# myRepro.objs_widget.clear()
items_count = myRepro.objs_widget.topLevelItemCount()
```

In the delete_item methods, there is this

```
mash_repro_utils.remove_mesh_group(myRepro.objs_widget.node, id)
mash_repro_utils.remove_proxy_group(self.node, self.instance_index, id)
```

I didn't had time to investigate but from there, you find :

```
print(mash_repro_utils.__file__)
# Result: 'maya_path/plug-ins/MASH/scripts/mash_repro_utils.py' #
```

Go there and there is all the maya python mash functions :

```
def remove_proxy_group(mash_repro_node, instance_index, index):
    """
    Remove a proxy object from the Repro node

    :param mash_repro_node: MASH Repro node
    :param instance_index: Object index
    :param index: Proxy index
    :return: None
    """
    with ReproUpdating(mash_repro_node):
        data = get_data_layout(mash_repro_node)
        indices = data[instance_index]['proxies'].keys()
        indices.sort()
        if index in indices:
            position = indices.index(index)
            for i in range(position, len(indices)):
                clean_proxy_index(mash_repro_node, instance_index, indices[i])
            for i in range(position + 1, len(indices)):
                if 'group' in data[instance_index]['proxies'][indices[i]]:
                    new_index = connect_proxy_group(mash_repro_node, data[instance_index]['proxies'][indices[i]]['group'], instance_index)
                    maya.cmds.setAttr("%s.instancedGroup[%d].proxyGroup[%d].proxyLod" % (mash_repro_node, instance_index, new_index), data[instance_index]['proxies'][indices[i]]['proxyLod'])
                    hasMASHFlag = maya.cmds.objExists('%s.mashOutFilter' % (data[instance_index]['proxies'][indices[i]]['group']))
                    if hasMASHFlag:
                        maya.cmds.deleteAttr( data[instance_index]['proxies'][indices[i]]['group'], at='mashOutFilter' )
```

You should be able to investigate from there.

You could just make your own delete_all, like this also:

```
items_count = myRepro.objs_widget.topLevelItemCount()
for id in sorted(range(items_count), reverse=True):
    mash_repro_utils.remove_mesh_group(myRepro.objs_widget.node, id)
    myRepro.objs_widget.obj_dropped.emit(None)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get your first line. What is this mash_repro_aetemplate.__file__) ?

Comment: if you print this, you will have the python file path. It is a default method in any module. you can import os, and then print(os.__file__).
So then you are able to open the python file with a text editor

Comment: and "mash_repro_aetemplate" is imported when you put "echo all command" and try to remove an item in the repro node. If it is a mel command, you use "whatIs command;", if it is python, you can use \__file\__ method. Here is another topic where i go in depth with my maya investigation with MEL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509231/maya-python-open-another-instance-of-the-attribute-editor/52514824#52514824

Comment: Cool. This helps me a lot to gop deeper in Mash. For this part I got an empty list : `code` widgets = get_maya_window().findChildren(qt.QWidget, 'AEMASH_ReproTemplate') or [] `code`
When I do "print widgets" -> []

Comment: **Sorry, just need to add**   `import mash_repro_aetemplate` so your script can work. I am still on it for the next phase

Comment: The problem is that `myRepro.objs_widget.topLevelItemCount()` gives 0 instead of the number of mesh (143)

Comment: **Sorry it works** I just have had an empty Mash network besides the good one

Comment: ah cool, the question was a bit difficult to answer by just a piece of code. Happy that it is working for you !

Comment: if you found this useful and it feel it answered your question, don't forgot to validate it ;)

Comment: I have just pressed the icon "this answer is useful" . What can I do more ?

Comment: Im not sure you can already upvote an answer (you seem to be a recent member). But to accept an answer, here it is : https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer